# sending checkbox via ajax and jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, database

I'm sending via **Ajax** and **Jquery** the value of checkboxes to my database, but when I refresh the page I'm not getting any result like if there is some kind of error somewhere.

```
$(".check_update").change(
function(){
 $.ajax(
    {
      type: "POST",
      url: "/_include/update.php",
      data: "player_id=95&parameter="+this.getAttribute("name")+"&value="+$(this)[0].value,
      success: function(result){
        if(result != 1){
            alert('update failed');
          console.log(result)
        }
      },
      dataType: "tinyint"
    }
  )
}
```

);

The database is setted to receive **tinyint** from the checkboxes.

Thanks for the help

Comment: `dataType: "tinyint"` ??? See DOC regarding dataType: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: which one must I use?

Comment: now it's working but not completely. I can uncheck but if I check they don't stay checked

Comment: Nothing in your posted code check/uncheck any checkboxes...

Comment: whit that code, when I uncheck a checkbox in the html page after a refresh the chechbox stays unchecked. So seems like in the database it's unchecked, but when I try to check a checkbox it remains unchecked

Comment: This code isn't called on page load but on onchange event of checkbox

Comment: so what I have to do? .click instead of change?